# Insert an email address into MySQL using a java application

Tags: java, mysql, email, insert

I am trying to insert an email address into a MySQL using a java application. The problem I am having is that the "@" character is causing a MySQLSyntaxErrorException. I try to insert the email address as a String. How do i fix this?

Comment: We...need....codes....

Comment: could be a lot of things, but most likely scenario is that youre building your SQL "by hand" (as a string with append() or + operators) instead of using a PreparedStatement and so youre not sanitizing the data. paste the code here and we'll know for sure

Answer (score 5):

```
 String insert = "INSERT INTO customer_tbl(name, email) VALUES (?,?)";
 PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(insert);
 ps.setString(1,"name");
 ps.setString(2,"freddy@slabbinck.net");
 ps.executeUpdate();
```

A prepared statement let you use placemarkers, which can be set to anything and is not parsed by the SQL parser. As an added bonus, this makes you also immune for SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

[Parameterize](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) your query using a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). This way you do not have to worry about manual string escaping and are less vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use PreparedStatement like in this example: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.sql/InsertPs.html